# MS Word Citation Field Codes Not Complete

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, bibliography

I'm writing a research article using (:-() MS Word, and having a problem with a multi-citation.  I'm trying to combine 4 articles in the same citation, and expect output like `(Poole & Rosenthal, 1985;1991;1999;2000`.  The citation field has this value `CITATION Poo85 \t\l 1033 \m Poo91 \n\t\l 1033  \m Poo99 \n\t\l 1033  \m Poo00 \n\t\l 1033`.  The bib keys Poo85/91/99/00 are all correct.  What I am instead getting is `(Poole & Rosenthal, 1985; 1991; 1999)`.  It's not an issue of with the last item.  If I transpose Poo99 and Poo00, I get the same behavior, but with Poo99 missing.

Someone Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Word 2010 only allows a certain number of sources per citations when titles are suppressed. This is considered a known bug y some, although Microsoft has not commented officially.

See this link for more details, and some ideas on how to control the maximum allowed entries (avoiding the /t seems to give some relief): http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/word-2010-only-allows-a-certain-number-of-sources/e1f41e42-bfc2-4541-addc-335a5c218a7d?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

For completeness in support of the answer by @Aganju, the workaround solution to this is to edit the style xml file to remove the () around citations. You need to updated the templ_prop_OpenBracket (and same for CloseBracket) elements to read:

`<xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=INITIAL_CONTENTLCID]/b:General/b:OpenBracket"/>
<xsl:text></xsl:text>`

You may then manually string together as many citations as you want, with whatever separator you want, and within whatever bracket style you want.  Of course, if you desire output as I did, the following citations should have their names and titles suppressed.